# How to pass number of posts in category to input upon choosing category from select in wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have made simple front end post creator in wordpress, via form. On the end of post user is prompted to select the category, and based on users selection, the number of posts of this very category should be passed to input and incremented by 1. (I am trying to make some kind of numeration, lake page number, or something, because it is more than important to my customer to have this.).

```
<select name="event-dropdown" onchange='document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'> 
<option value=""><?php echo esc_attr(__('Select Category')); ?></option> 

<?php 
    $option = '<option value="' . get_option('home') . '/category/">All Categories</option>'; // change category to your custom page slug
    $categories = get_categories(); 
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $option .= '<option value="'.get_option('home').'/category/'.$category->slug.'">';
        $option .= $category->cat_name;
        $option .= ' ('.$category->category_count.')';
        $option .= '</option>';
    }
    echo $option;
?>
```

So basically from this  I have to pass the number of posts to simple  and increment it by one.

I have tried to use jQuery to read the select and than choose only number and pass it, but it did not work...

Comment: Come on guys, anyone?! I really need this. It's for my job....

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found solution. I added custom attribute to option and via jQuery I passed number of posts to input field.

```
 <select id="cat" class="cat" name="newcat"  >
        <option value="0"><?php echo esc_attr(__('Izaberite vozilo')); ?>
</option>
        <?php
           $categories= get_categories(array('orderby ' => 'id' , 'order' => 'DESC' ,'hide_empty' => 0 , 'hierarchical' => true)); 
           foreach ($categories as $category) {
           $option = '<option value="'.$category->term_id.' " broj="'.$category->category_count.'" cat-id-broj="'.$category->term_id.'">';
           $option .= $category->cat_name; 
           $option .= '</option>';
           echo $option;
           }
           ?>
     </select>
```

and then this is jQuery code

```
  var proba = $('#cat').change(function() { 
 var probavanje = $('option:selected', this).attr('cat-id-broj'); 

if (probavanje == 17) {
$("#probavanje").val('2000 kg');
$("#masa-unos").val('10 000kg');
$('#registarski-broj').val('E25-JK2');
}
else if (probavanje == 18) {
$("#probavanje").val('5000 kg');
$("#masa-unos").val('15 000kg');
$('#registarski-broj').val('33N-25V');
}
else if (probavanje == 19) {
$("#probavanje").val('20 kg');
$("#masa-unos").val('15kg');
$('#registarski-broj').val('NNN-023');
}
else if (probavanje == 1) {
$("#probavanje").val('');
$("#masa-unos").val('');
$('#registarski-broj').val('');
}
```